# How can I hide comment of the authors from their published posts?

Tags: comments, author

### How can I hide the comment of my authors about their own posts?
I used plugins and it was successful, but the comments are displayed somewhere onthe posts of authors themselves and i cant do anything about that

I have several authors and I want only admin to be able to see or approve them. That's why I want him not to see any of the opinions (his own comment or the comment of others). But when I published it, he had no problem seeing it. I just do not want the comment to be displayed when not approved by admin so how can i do it? I hid them from the admin panel by the plugin but they are displayed inside their published posts (I mean unconfirmed comments)

Comment: So you've hidden them from the post page but they're showing up on the author pages? I think it would be easier to just ban authors commenting on their own posts rather than letting them and then trying to hide the comments afterwards. But why shouldn't authors be allowed to comment on their own posts?

Comment: Or is published the key word here: your goal to allow authors to comment on drafts? But then I'd guess you don't want any of the comments on the draft to be visible on the published post, not just the authors? So delete them on publish?